# How do you get Ruby documentation in Texinfo format?

Tags: ruby, texinfo

I created the documentation for Python in Texinfo format via help from this question:

[How do you get Python documentation in Texinfo Info format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054903/how-do-you-get-python-documentation-in-texinfo-info-format)

Now I want the same for Ruby.

Is the Ruby documentation available in Texinfo format?

or

Is there any easy way to create one `.info` file containing the documentation for Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 1):

I never needed it myself, but `RDoc` seems to have a generator for TexInfo, so you may be able to generate it yourself:

```
http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/RDoc.html
http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/files/lib/rdoc/generator/texinfo_rb.html
```

There also is an unmaintained project on GitHub:

```
https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc-texinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michael - the github project appears to have the same code as what is behind the ruby-doc pages you cite, which is incomplete.

```
    # TODO: create info files and install?
```

is from http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/RDoc/Generator/TEXINFO.src/M003851.html